# Using an Anonymous Thread in Delphi to blink a label

Tags: multithreading, delphi

I need to do a label to blink 5 times using a thread.

When I click on the button, I need the label blinks 5 times.

Now, I have a problem.

when I close the form I have a Memory Leak on Thread.

What am I doing wrong here?

```
type
  TForm1= class(TForm)
  ...
  labelNewMsg:Tlabel;
  private
    MEvent: TEvent;

procedure Torm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
begin
  MEvent := TEvent.Create(nil, False, False, '');
  waitNewMessage();
end;  

procedure TForm1.FormDestroy(Sender: TObject);
begin
  MEvent.Free;
end;

procedure TForm1.ButtonDoSetEventClick(Sender: TObject);
begin
 Mevent.SetEvent;
end;


procedure TForm1.waitNewMessage;
var
    Status:TWaitResult;
begin
     TThread.CreateAnonymousThread(
        procedure
        var IntCnt: Integer;
        begin
           while not TThread.CurrentThread.CheckTerminated and (not application.terminated) do begin
            Sleep(100);
            Status:=MEvent.WaitFor(INFINITE);
            if Status=wrSignaled then begin
              for IntCnt:=1 to 5 do begin
                Sleep(1000);
                TThread.Synchronize(nil,procedure begin
                  labelNewMsg.Visible:=not labelNewMsg.Visible;
                end);
              end;
              IntCnt:=0;
              MEvent.ResetEvent;
            end;
           end;
        end
      ).Start;
end;
```

Hi, I created a second option, but I have the same problem:

```
procedure TFrm_PrincipalDemo.waitNewMessage;
var
    Status:TWaitResult;
begin
      TThread.CreateAnonymousThread(
        procedure
        var IntCnt: Integer;
        begin
           while MEvent.WaitFor(INFINITE) in [wrSignaled] do begin
              if TThread.CurrentThread.CheckTerminated then exit;
              MEvent.ResetEvent;
              Sleep(100);
              for IntCnt:=1 to 5 do begin
                Sleep(1000);
                TThread.Synchronize(nil,procedure begin
                  labelNewMsg.Visible:=not labelNewMsg.Visible;
                end);
              end;
              if TThread.CurrentThread.CheckTerminated then exit;
           end;
        end
      ).Start;
end;
```

Comment: The anonymous thread is leaking because you never exit from threadproc and so the TThread object is never freed. Insert Exit/Break after resetting event. But then the blinking will happen only once and you should create another thread to blink again.

Comment: @Sertac Akyuz  I created a second option as you said, but I have the same problem of memory leak. I´d like to create only a thread to do it and call setEvent when I need.

Comment: That's not what I said. I said insert exit/break just after MEvent.ResetEvent in first option. Note that the thread will be freed only if you blink.

Comment: @Sertac Akyuz  But I need to stay in the thread. I don´t want to exit from it. I´d prefer don´t create another thread

Comment: Then don't use an anonymous thread, because you need a reference to get rid of it when you terminate your program. Or, let the thread leak since you're terminating anyway.

Comment: Looks like your code is way overcomplicated based on the requirements

Comment: Don't use a thread. Use a timer.

Answer (score 6):

You are not signaling the thread to terminate itself before your Form is closed.  For instance, if the thread is blocked waiting for `MEvent`, you need to signal `MEvent` so the thread can wake up and check for termination.

The `Application.Terminated` property is not set to `True` until the main message loop has processed a `WM_QUIT` message from `PostQuitMessage()`, which `Application.Terminate()` calls.  The program's `Application.MainForm` calls `Application.Terminate()` when the Form is closed (not destroyed, that comes later).

If you keep a reference to the `TThread` object that you create, you can then call the `TThread.Terminate()` method directly, which sets the thread's `Terminated` property to True (otherwise, there is no point in calling `TThread.CheckTerminated()` inside of the thread at all), eg:

```pascal
type
  TForm1 = class(TForm)
    ...
    labelNewMsg: TLabel;
    ButtonDoSetEvent: TButton;
    ...
    procedure FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
    procedure FormClose(Sender: TObject; Action: TCloseAction);
    procedure FormDestroy(Sender: TObject);
    procedure ButtonDoSetEventClick(Sender: TObject);
    ...
  private
    MEvent: TEvent;
    Thread: TThread;
    procedure waitNewMessage;
    procedure ThreadTerminated(Sender: TObject);
    ...
  end;

procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
begin
  MEvent := TEvent.Create(nil, False, False, '');
  waitNewMessage();
end;  

procedure TForm1.FormClose(Sender: TObject; Action: TCloseAction);
begin
  if Thread <> nil then
  begin
    Thread.Terminate;
    MEvent.SetEvent;
  end;
end;

procedure TForm1.FormDestroy(Sender: TObject);
begin
  if Thread <> nil then
    Thread.OnTerminate := nil;
  MEvent.Free;
end;

procedure TForm1.ButtonDoSetEventClick(Sender: TObject);
begin
  MEvent.SetEvent;
end;

procedure TForm1.waitNewMessage;
begin
  Thread := TThread.CreateAnonymousThread(
    procedure
    var
      IntCnt: Integer;
      Status: TWaitResult;
    begin
      while not TThread.CheckTerminated do begin
        Sleep(100);
        Status := MEvent.WaitFor(INFINITE);
        if (Status = wrSignaled) and (not TThread.CheckTerminated) then begin
          for IntCnt := 1 to 5 do begin
            Sleep(1000);
            TThread.Synchronize(nil,
              procedure
              begin
                labelNewMsg.Visible := not labelNewMsg.Visible;
              end
            );
          end;
        end;
      end;
    end
  );
  Thread.OnTerminate := ThreadTerminated;
  Thread.Start;
end;

procedure TForm1.ThreadTerminated(Sender: TObject);
begin
  Thread := nil;
end;
```

But really, why are you even using a thread at all?  Nothing your thread does actually needs to be in a thread in the first place.  A simple timer would suffice instead, and it would be safer for the UI, and easier to stop during program shutdown.

```pascal
type
  TForm1 = class(TForm)
    ...
    labelNewMsg: TLabel;
    ButtonDoSetEvent: TButton;
    NewMsgTimer: TTimer;
    ...
    procedure ButtonDoSetEventClick(Sender: TObject);
    procedure NewMsgTimerTimer(Sender: TObject);
    ...
  end;

procedure TForm1.ButtonDoSetEventClick(Sender: TObject);
begin
  NewMsgTimer.Tag := 0;
  NewMsgTimer.Enabled := True;
end;

procedure TForm1.NewMsgTimerTimer(Sender: TObject);
begin
  NewMsgTimer.Tag := NewMsgTimer.Tag + 1;
  labelNewMsg.Visible := not labelNewMsg.Visible;
  if NewMsgTimer.Tag = 5 then
    NewMsgTimer.Enabled := False;
end;
```